# Add a IP to another rule matching hex in iptables linux

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables

**iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 4578 -m string --hex-string '|fefffffffffffffffff77f12|'**

How can I whitelist the IP having the above hexx string automatically on Iptables.

I'll be dropping all incoming traffic on iptables and allowing only the packet with above hex string. Whenever we receive a packet with above hex string the I want to whitelist his IP on Iptables immediately. So that all traffic from that particular IP gets passed

Thanks in Advance

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584824/run-a-system-command-when-an-iptables-rule-is-matched) entry on stack overflow suggests using the iptables log to catch logged matches and perform actions. There's also a link there to [this](https://medium.com/@farizmuradov/useful-notes-about-nfqueue-80a2c271db1a) which suggests using `nfqueue`, which is probably the most robust way to do it.

Comment: @A.B Can you please help me with those commands? Because I really don't know regarding mark and connmark just heard about it

Comment: @A.B I'll edit the port with the vaild values :)

Comment: @A.B Done.. :-)

Comment: @A.B I'll be dropping all incoming traffic on iptables and allowing only the packet with above hex string. Whenever we receive a packet with above hex string the I want to whitelist his IP on Iptables immediately. So that all traffic from that particular IP gets passed

Comment: @A.B Its full in detail now :)

Comment: This sounds like an incomplete concept. When will the IP lose its trusted status? // Maybe some combination of firewall marking and ipset could do it.

Comment: @DanielB I'll have a bash script which will remove IPs after 2hrs

Comment: @A.B Can you please share the commands bro :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP wishes to implement a very crude (because there's a single knock) [port knocker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking).

My advice would be to use a tool like [`fwknop`](https://www.cipherdyne.org/fwknop/) for Single Packet Authentication instead: doesn't send the secret in the clear, prevents [replay attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack) and is easy to integrate with firewall rules.

---

Anyway to answer the question. OP didn't state the system is a router, so I'll consider the system is a simple host. For a router, rules appearing in filter's `INPUT` should be adapted for use in filter's `FORWARD` instead or in addition.

The method is to:

- prepare a store to act as memory for IPs currently allowed: [*ipset*](https://ipset.netfilter.org/), and define its default timeout so entries will expire without additional script

  > If you want to
  >
  > - store multiple IP addresses or port numbers and match against the collection by iptables at one swoop;
  >
  > [...]

  There's at least one other choice such as the [`recent`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#recent) *iptables* module, but it's not so flexible in case changes are needed later.

  ```
  ipset create allowedset hash:ip timeout 120
  ```

  Note for integration at boot: this set must be created before the *iptables* rules referencing it are added or loaded or *iptables* will fail loading these rules (or `iptables-restore` the whole ruleset that includes these rules).
- add the IP of the succeeding client to the memory store using [`-j SET`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#SET) (reusing and fixing OP's rule which was in the *raw* table for... reasons?):

  ```
  iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING 1 -p udp --dport 4578 -m string --algo bm --hex-string '|fefffffffffffffffff77f12|' -j SET --add-set allowedset src
  ```
- Add usual boilerplate for a stateful firewall (this could have more details handled):

  ```
  iptables -I INPUT 1 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
  iptables -I INPUT 2 -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP

  iptables -I INPUT 3 -i lo -j ACCEPT
  ```
- When the first packet of a new flow appears, using [`-m set`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#set) check if this flow is from an IP stored before, if so allow the packet

  ```
  iptables -I INPUT 4 -m set --match-set allowedset src -j ACCEPT
  ```
- drop anything else (or else set the default policy to drop)

  ```
  iptables -I INPUT 5 -j DROP
  ```

The timeout was defined to 120: 2mn. This is the window during which new flows can be established. Once established (eg: an SSH remote connection or an UDP-based tunnel), it can stay established forever as long as activity makes it stay established (for UDP, from the point of view of Netfilter's *conntrack*, that's activity in less than 120s for flows having seen multiple exchanges, or less than 30s else).

---

Other options could have been used to not allow flows to continue past the timeout (which would then need to be greater, like OP's 2 hours), but this would have made it more difficult to integrate with a system that should still be able to initiate its own communications to outside.

Comment: Firstly Thanks for helping me out . But yes you're right the attack will pass through if its of the same packet. After checking the packets flow I found out the series such as 1) Incoming Packet fefffffffffffffffff77f12 2) Then application replies to that packet 3) Then the third packet is ffffffff636f6e6e656374203438. Is it possible to check 2 packets and then whitelist the IPS?

Comment: I mean to say if the two packets are in series from single source ip:source port then whitelisting that source ip

Comment: You're asking a new question. I suggest instead to think about it before implementing it. This new version is still subject to 1/ secret leak 2/ replay attack. You really should consider fwknop which is protected against both.  Also here's a paragraph on nftables' wiki on how to implement multiple knocks (using nftables rather than iptables): https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Port_knocking_example